# Negative X,Y Coordinates to linear array index?

Tags: c++, arrays, coordinates

I have been (unsuccessfully ) attempting to convert the negative coordinates of a 2d coordinate grid into a linear index intended for placing within an array.

```
std::vector<float> heights(20*20);
for ( int x = -10; x < 10; x++ ) {
    for ( int y = -10; y < 10; y++ ) {
        heights[20*x + y] = NoiseGenerator.GetPerlinFractal(x, y);
    }
}
```

The above is a simplified version of what I was doing *before* I attempted to use negative coordinates.

Honestly, I'm at a loss. This seems like it should be *extremely* simple to solve, but here I am feeling stupid after a solid 2 hours of no results and plenty of out_of_range exceptions :)

I'd appreciate any help anyone can give me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Printing `20*x + y` before accessing the array is a good idea I guess.

Comment: std::map<int, float> can accept negatives in square braces. (or one of other hash types)

Comment: @titapo That's horrible advice if you don't ask first about performance requirements. `std::map` has `log(n)` access complexity.

Comment: haha, yes, performance is a concern, it's why I'm putting all the information into a linear structure to begin with. This is intended for use in a renderer and the function which contains the algorithm will be executed quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `heights[(x - x_min) * rows + (y - y_min)]`?

Here `x_min` and `y_min` are both -10, and `rows` is 20.

Note that `x_max` and `y_max` will both be 9, as you allow 20 points in each dimension. 21 would have been more symmetric.

Recovering `x` and `y` from a given `index` in your vector will require using integer division and `%`.